# Query specific uid in Firebase using Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Im really confused on how to query a single record in firebase by the uid.
I have a user id and want to query the following table. I am using the following code.
However, it is returning both the records instead of just the 'this.selectedId' one. Is there 1) A way to just return the record being queried 2) keep the key instead of array of index 0, 1, 2, 3 etc...

Code used

```
const itemsRef = this.afs.collection<any>(`/profiles/`);
itemsRef.valueChanges(this.selectedId).subscribe(
    x => {
      console.log("Value change", x);
    }
);
```

Image

[image: This is the structure.]

Returned result
[image]

Comment: Please don't include a screenshot of your result. Copy the text into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `valueChanges` method doesn't take any parameters. If you want to [monitor a single document](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#streaming-document-data)

```
const itemRef = this.afs.doc<any>(`/profiles/`+this.selectedId);
itemRef.valueChanges()...
```